# java.lang.ClassCastException: trail1modified cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am using jGRASP. it has a function where I can run the program as an applet. But i get this error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: trail1modified cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:785)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:714)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: post the source of `trail1modified`

Comment: I am new to java/programming. What do you mean by 'source'?

Comment: priceless comment...

Answer (score 2):

your class `trail1modified` does not extend `java.applet.Applet` or any of its subclasses.